# Как создать несколько Checkbutton в цикле и сохранить значения в список?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

list_cb = []
value = 0

def print_list_cb():
    print (list_cb)

for i in range(10):
    list_cb.append(0)
    cb = Checkbutton(root, height=2, variable=list_cb[i])
    cb.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='print', command=print_list_cb)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Здравствуйте.

Я пытаюсь создать 10 чекбоксов так, чтобы можно было хранить и изменять их состояния в списке (даже лучше, пожалуй, в словаре). Знаю, что такой код принципиально неверен, но не представляю, куда копать. Собственно, код привожу для того, чтобы был предмет обсуждения. Натыкался в сети на упоминания об использовании замыкания в таких случаях, но ясных примеров найти не смог. Буду благодарен за разъяснения на максимально доступном новичку языке. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Чуть-чуть изменил ваш код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list_cb = []
for j in range(10):
    list_cb.append(IntVar())

def print_list_cb():
    list_of_cb_values = []
    for i in range(10):
        list_of_cb_values.append(list_cb[i].get())
    print(list_of_cb_values)

for i in range(10):
    cb = Checkbutton(root, height=2, variable=list_cb[i])
    cb.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='print', command=print_list_cb)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Убрал переменную value и убрал в цикле for i in range(10) дополнение списка нулём, эти "дела" не нужны. Для работы с Checkbutton (и, если не ошибаюсь, с Radiobutton) нужно в variable заключать переменную типа IntVar() - она служит для работы с целыми числами. Я создал список из таких переменных для присваивания всем Checkbutton'ам такие переменные.

Перейдём к функции print_list_cb(). У нас есть список list_cb в котором заключены все значения наших "флажков", но print(IntVar()) нам даст не то, что мы хотели, поэтому получаем из IntVar() каждого чекбаттона значение методом get() и закидываем в список list_of_cb_values. Теперь выводим этот список через print().

Если же вам нужно постоянное "наблюдение" за флажками (т.е. только флажок выбрал, переменная сразу обновилась, не дожидаясь вызова print_list_cb(), просто внесите

```
list_of_cb_values = []
for i in range(10):
    list_of_cb_values.append(list_cb[i].get())
```

в цикл while, а

```
print(list_of_cb_values)
```

оставьте в print_list_cb().

Но, как по мне, вместо while будет целесообразнее добавить в checkbutton - command.
В итоге будет:

```
Checkbutton(root, height=2, variable=list_cb[i], command=some_command)
```

Т.е. при нажатии "флажка", будет сразу выполнятся some_command()

Comment: Спасибо за исключительную ясность ответа. Теперь, наконец, сдвинусь с точки, на которой застрял так надолго. Кстати, не знал, что Checkbutton тоже можно назначать инструкцию "command=...".

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!